# passing HTTP access logs to Kibana with fluentd

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd, access-log

I am trying to view HTTP access logs from Kibana but was unable to do so.

Sample HTTP access logs.

```
- 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Apr/2021:12:18:45.378 +0530] "GET /pizzashack/1.0.0/menu HTTP/1.1" - - "https://localhost:9443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"
- 127.0.0.1 - [12/Apr/2021:12:18:45.378 +0530] "- - " 401 - "-" "-"
```

Sample fluent.conf file

```
 <source>
     @type tail
     path /logs/http_access_.log
     pos_file /logs/http_access_.log.pos
     tag httpaccess
     format /(?<host>-\s*[^ ]*)(?<user>\s*[^ ]* [^ ]*\s*)\[(?<dateNtime>[^ ]*\s*[^ ]*)\]\s*(?<request>[^ ]*\s*[^ ]*\s*[^ ]*)\s*(?<statuscode>[^ ]*)\s*(?<size>[^ ]*)\s*(?<url>[^ ]*)\s*(?<message>.*)/

 </source>

 <match httpaccess>
     @type copy
     <store>
         @type elasticsearch
         host elasticsearch
         port 9200
         include_tag_key true
         include_timestamp true
         tag_key @log_name2
         logstash_format true
         logstash_prefix access.${tag}
         flush_interval 5s
     </store>
 </match>
```

As per this [site](https://regex101.com/) it seems the format is correct.
But with the above, I could not see the logs in Kibana. Appreciate if someone can help me to resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you see in the fluentd logs? I'm not sure if the logs are in logstash format. If not, use `logstash_format false`. The fluentd debug logs would reveal more. Maybe, you need to run fluentd with debug mode.

Comment: Thanks. But with `logstash_format false` also no luck.  I think there is no errors. logs can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XR-ebVYnbO-Yt4w3VijZ-ESG3-rURDeO2Qfn797gG7E/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work with below format.

```
format_firstline /-\s*\d{3}.\d{0,3}.\d{0,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,3}/
format1 /^(?<host>-\s*\d{3}.\d{0,3}.\d{0,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,3})(?<user>\s*[^ ]* [^ ]*\s*)\[(?<time>[^ ]*\s*[^ ]*)\]\s*(?<request>[^ ]*\s*[^ ]*\s*[^ ]*)\s*(?<statuscode>[^ ]*)\s*(?<size>[^ ]*)\s*(?<address>[^ ]*)\s*(?<agent>.*)/
```

Thanks.